# How to make wordpress site as mobile compatible

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site working fine in all browsers. Now I want to make it compatible with mobile phones. how is it possible?. I had used twenty eleven theme for making the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some plugins and themes that can help you with that. 
I've used [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-pack/) and it works pretty good with most phones.
You can always [search](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=mobile%20version&sort=) on WordPress' site

Comment: can i use the same twenty eleven theme with WordPress Mobile Pack

Comment: You could, but then you'd need to restyle it so it looks better on smaller sceens. 
Still, phones with modern browsers should display it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

worpress mobile pack is good.. some more alternatives :
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mobile-detector/ 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mobilepress/